# Server-side template parsing

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js, rhino

I'm currently exploring how to use HandlebarsJS via a server-side parser.

Unfortunately we are limited to using RhinoJS server.

I've searched high and low to find out how to use HandlebarsJS via the server side. I can see how to register a helper and various other things, but I'm curious to know if it's possible to parse a JS or HTML file and have the various portions of the file replaced with the server generated content?

I'm hoping this is possible without using something like node and optimistic that it's possible to parse the file just like you would do using PHP or CFML but using JS under RhinoJS instead.

Any suggestions greatly appreciated.

Comment: You could load an HTML (template) file via AJAX (as HTML) and parse it as a Handlebars template using helpers.

Comment: "RhinoJS server" — What is RhinoJS server? I'm aware of Rhino (which is a way of running JS) but how are you linking it to HTTP requests?